# A huge gap between navbar component and home component

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, routes

I am working on an Angular Project and I have to put my navbar in another component to make my routing work. But because of this, I have this huge gap between my navbar and home component. I'm not sure on how you get rid of this. Can someone help me?

Comment: share your code

Comment: it's just css issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some problem with import or routing or may be you must've imported other blank component that's causing gap betweem navbar and home components.